# Evaluate a String in a Play Framework 2 Template as Scala code

Tags: playframework-2.0

In a view of a Scala Play Framework 2 project, I want to display a snippet of source code verbatim like this:

```
@if(true) { "The world has ended!" }
```

Followed by the compiled result:

```
"The world has ended!"
```

I want to do this by defining a method that accepts a `String` containing the snippet, and outputs both versions, something like this:

```
@sideBySide(content: String) = {
  content -> eval(content)
}
```

I would call it like this:

```
@sideBySide("""@if(false) { "The world has ended!" }""")
```

So the problem is how to write `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

First, a disclaimer, I really hope that you understand what kind of a can of worms you open by having a js-like eval available and that you have thought through this very carefully. :)

I have reused the Scala Console in a small little project I did to be able to evaluate Scala code inside a Deck.js presentation, this is the code, should help you get figure out *one* way of doing it (I'm afraid I can't exactly recall the rationale behind the classloader trixery):

```
val settings: Settings = {

  lazy val urls = java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader match {
    case cl: java.net.URLClassLoader => cl.getURLs.toList
    case _ => sys.error("classloader is not a URLClassLoader")
  }

  lazy val classpath = urls map {_.toString}

  val tmp = new Settings()
  tmp.bootclasspath.value = classpath.distinct mkString File.pathSeparator
  tmp
}

val interpreter = new IMain(settings)

def unsafeEval(source: String): String = 
  stringFromStream { sout =>
     Console.withOut(sout) {
       interpreter.interpret(source)
     }
  }

// lets someone write to a stream and then we return the string contents of that stream
def stringFromStream(f: (OutputStream) => Any): String = {
  val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  f(out)
  out.toString("UTF-8")
}
```

Comment: You can call it like any Scala code from templates. Say you put it in @some.package.SomeObject.eval(source) or by first importing it into the scope with an @import statement.

Comment: I think I figured out what you intended. There is still a problem, so I made a gist https://gist.github.com/mslinn/7205854

Comment: Hmmmm. If you want to be able to do it like that @eval(List(1,2,3).map(_*2).mkString), i think you will have to write a macro that returns both the code as a string (rendering the AST?) and calls it, my solution only works if you provide the expression as a string.

Comment: That was an error, I should have written  @eval("List(1,2,3).map(_*2).mkString")

Comment: I think the 'object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found' is because you need to have the compiler jar on the classpath of your project, so you probably need to add it as a dependency.

Comment: I do not think this approach will work. Instead of calling the Scala compiler, I need to invoke the Plate template evaluator by passing in a string. We know this because the string to be evaluated has an @ in it.

Comment: In that case it gets even more complicated because you will first have to do a pass using the template compiler (and to do that it needs to be a valid template) which emits Scala code and then compile that with the Scala compiler to be able to evaluate it.

Comment: Unless there is a way to pass the template compiler a string to evaluate. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/templates-compiler/src/main/scala/play/templates/ScalaTemplateCompiler.scala